# Can I add a Like Button to a website to link it to a personal Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

Can I add a Like button to a customer's website in order to link it to a personal Facebook page, not a professional/business Facebook page? When trying to do so, Facebook did not recognize a personal Facebook URL.

Answer (score 0):

No, Likes are only for Pages, not personal profiles. You might consider a [`fb:subscribe`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/) button, though.

EDIT: I take that back, you can use a like button if you want. But the profile itself won't fans, since there are no fans of profiles; rather, the graph object tied to that profile will get likes.

You might also consider [migrating to a page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php?migrate).

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can use the subscribe social plugin - similar to likes but for personal users.

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/